# Error creating bean with name 'cxf'

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error on running my program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
```

my test.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">


    <bean id="clientI"
        class="LI" />
    <bean id="clientL"
        class="LIn" />

        <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="clientI" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="clientL" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

Comment: do you have cxf-bundle-xxx.jar in your classpath?

Comment: can you paste the entire exception chain - including all of the causes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have cxf-bundle JAR in your classpath? Because this could be the problem.

You can get it from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-bundle/2.7.6 (the latest version).

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible because you are using an old version of neethi (maybe 2.X.X) and you should use version 3.0.2. Check your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For a resolution I had to add both cxf-bundle-xxx.jar and updated the neethi jar with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on an EAR including an cxf-WebService deployed in WebSphere AS,

it may result from the class loader of the of the cxf-WebService-Module. Be shure that you set the class loader of the WebService-Module to PARENT_LAST